# Format SSD with nvme : LBA Format specified is not supported

Tags: ssd, fedora, format, nvme

I would like to erase a SSD under Fedora 32 using `nvme` utility and I get this message : "LBA Format specified is not supported".

`nvme --version`

*nvme version 1.10.1*

`nvme list`

*Node : /dev/nvme0n1*

*Namespace : 1*

*Format : 512   B +  0 B*

`sudo nvme id-ctrl /dev/nvme0n1 -H`

*fna : 0*

*[2:2] : 0 Crypto Erase Not Supported as part of Secure Erase*

*[1:1] : 0 Crypto Erase Applies to Single Namespace(s)*

*[0:0] : 0 bFormat Applies to Single Namespace(s)*

`sudo nvme format -s1 /dev/nvme0n1`

*You are about to format nvme0n1, namespace 0x1.*

*Namespace nvme0n1 has parent controller(s):nvme0*

*WARNING: Format may irrevocably delete this device's data.*

*You have 10 seconds to press Ctrl-C to cancel this operation.*

*Use the force [--force|-f] option to suppress this warning.*

*Sending format operation ...*

*NVMe status: INVALID_FORMAT: **The LBA Format specified is not supported**. This may be due to various conditions(0x10a)*

I tried to add the `-lb=0` option as mentioned [in the comments here](http://blog.pythonaro.com/2018/05/how-to-securely-wipe-nvme-drive.html) but I got the same message.

Could you please help me to find out what's going wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Finally I found the solution [here](https://community.wd.com/t/sn750-cannot-format-using-the-nvme-command/254374/8) :

*"I put the computer to sleep and then, after resume, the lock was released and the format command was ok."*

Thanks for reading.

Comment: "the suspend trick did not work" I tried `systemctl suspend` (ubuntu) and it worked. thanks